# Can I tell if I'm running in systemd?

Tags: systemd

I have a Python service in systemd. I'd like to have it use the Python `syslog` module for logging if it's running in systemd vs. otherwise. Is there a reliable way to determine if I'm running in systemd or is there a better way of going about it?

Comment: why not have your python program have a flag like `--syslog`, then pass that flag with the `systemd` service?

Comment: I can do that. I was just wondering if there's still a way to determine whether I'm in SystemD.

Comment: `ps -q 1 -o comm=`...

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/926349/systemd-tell-if-script-was-run-by-systemd-or-by-user

Answer (score 2):

`systemd` will always have a PID of 1, so you can check if the parent PID is 1:

```
import psutil, os
if psutil.Process(os.getpid()).ppid() == 1:
    # We are using systemd
```

However, it's probally better to offer a command line flag `--syslog` and pass that with the `systemd` service, this way the user can select to use syslog even without the `systemd` service.

Comment: Won't init also be pid 1?

Comment: @JeffSchaller hence the reason I recommend the command line flag

Comment: Not working for me.